# Proving the orthogonality of Square Matrix and its Transpose

Tags: matrices, matlab, orthogonal-matrices

I've a square matrix, that has an equal number of rows and columns. So how should I prove its orthogonality? Been searching around, but couldn't find something that could be helpful.

Here's a given DCT-matrix, which I've to find the orthogonality of:

```
    mat = [0.5000   0.5000   0.5000   0.5000   
    0.6533   0.2706  -0.2706  -0.6533
    0.5000  -0.5000  -0.5000   0.5000  
    0.2706  -0.6533   0.6533  -0.2706];
```

Which I did. The square matrix and its transpose is given below with following commands.

```
>> mat*mat' %%Transpose
>> mat'*mat %%Square

ans =

    1.0000         0         0         0
         0    1.0001         0         0
         0         0    1.0000         0
         0         0         0    1.0001


ans =

    1.0000    0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000
    0.0000    1.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000
   -0.0000   -0.0000    1.0000    0.0000
   -0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000    1.0000
```

As I understand by reading from this site: [Click Here](https://byjus.com/maths/orthogonal-matrix/)
It says "*when the product of a square matrix and its transpose gives an identity matrix, then the square matrix is known as an orthogonal matrix.*"

If you ask me, then I can actually see the orthogonality, since it's mostly identity diagonal, the thing is will the +0.0001 make a difference, since two of the numbers are 1.0001 and the others are 1.0000? it is stated that it is orthogonal in the task description, just want to be sure.

My question is: Is the matrix orthogonal?

Comment: The error is probably due to floating point number imprecision. Never forget that real numbers are generally irrational, and thus have no internal repeating patterns, so would take an infinite amount of memory to be represented. Hence, all floating point numbers in computers are discrete approximations of real numbers. Yes, your matrix is quite probably orthogonal.

Comment: Thank you. Just to be sure, so it is orthogonal because that both matrices have a diagonal result with the same real numbers?

Comment: No, it is orthogonal because the product of a matrix with its transpose is equal to the identity matrix, meaning that your matrix's transpose is also your matrix's inverse. This is a property that is true iff your matrix is orthogonal.